# how do i debug AFMultipartFormData' content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking library's AFMultipartFormData to upload an image and few strings. there is some issue on the server side with respect to the encoding scheme. I need to see what is the actual data which is sent from the app for multipart form data request. What is the best way to see the post body which is fired form the iPhone app. Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution? Even I am facing the same issue.